# NHibernate throws this error 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException' when I'm trying to update a table using DML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here and I'd like to know what's wrong with code below:

```
var hqlUpdate = "UPDATE Enrollment SET status = 'Approved' WHERE Id = :studentId && Level = :level && Semester = :semester";
        Database.Session.CreateQuery(hqlUpdate)
            .SetParameter("studentId", id)
            .SetString("level", studentLevel)
            .SetString("semester", semester)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: try replacing && with `and` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace `&&` with `and`. I dont think HQL supports `&&`